# PL/SQL Triggers - Row Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to use a row trigger that updates all salaries using the formula: 
`Salary = salary * 1.1`.

The table created is as follows: `Employee (EmployeeID, Name, Address, Phone, Salary)`.

Comment: This is a poor piece of "business logic" even by the standards of the homework questions we see on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simple create such type of trigger :

```
create or replace trigger trg_upd_salaries 
after update on Employee
for each row
begin
  :new.salary := :new.salary * 1.1;
end;
/
```

Triggers are structures primarily intended to be fired during DML operations. It's meaningless to re-select already inserted values to be updated inside triggers, apply classical `update` statements to change already inserted values.

Comment: Am having the following error:
ORA-04084: cannot change new values for this trigger type.
I tried to change AFTER UPDATE  to BEFORE UPDATE , the trigger is then created, but the changes in salary applies to the new insert only.
How about the data already inserted beforehand?

Comment: @Panda18 triggers are structures primarily intended to be fired during DML operations. It's meaningless to re-select already inserted values to be updated here.

Comment: Well noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `:NEW` and multiplying it `* 1.1`, implemented like that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_updatesalaries
BEFORE UPDATE ON Employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.salary := :NEW.salary * 1.1;
END;
/
```

Comment: Am having the following error:
ORA-04084: cannot change new values for this trigger type.
I tried to change AFTER UPDATE  to BEFORE UPDATE , the trigger is then created, but the changes in salary applies to the new insert only.
How about the data already inserted beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you don't need a trigger. You need an `UPDATE` statement:

```
update employee set
  salary = salary * 1.1;
```

That will raise all existing salaries by 10%.

However, if you do need to do it for every new row inserted into a table, then yes - you'd need a trigger. 
Though, what's the purpose in doing that? Insert valid value at once, don't (re)calculate it.